# fill image with color except transparent part in php

Tags: php

I Want to fill a transparent image.
I want to fill only the visible part, not the transparent one, but my code is acting the opposite.

Please help me

Here is my code to fill my transparent image

```
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("ff6600.png");
$width = imagesx($im);    $height = imagesy($im);
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 25, 25, 112);

imagefill($im,0,0,$blue);

imagesavealpha($im, TRUE);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: try to add `imagealphablending($im, true);` after `imagefill`

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting